# Apache Velocity IfNotNull

Tags: java, velocity

[This link](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull) describes how to use `if not null` condition in velocity.

```
userdirective = org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.directive.Ifnull
userdirective = org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.directive.Ifnotnull
```

But looking inside [velocity tools jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools/2.0) there is no such class `org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.directive.Ifnotnull`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link:

> Use a custom directive. cf. IfNullDirective, IfNotNullDirective

You have to put the linked code (http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/IfNullDirective and http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/IfNotNullDirective) in your sources, it's not provided in the regular velocity jar.

Comment: Thanks - the Chinese solution, copy & paste.